# cannot add property 0 object is not extensible React.js 84 строка

Tags: reactjs

Explosion={this.Explosion} если пытаюсь изменить состояние страничка падает, но если делаю там другие манипуляции (по типу консоллога) то все работает

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Mine from "./images/mine.png";
var N = 10;

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function Fill(arr){
  for(var i = 0; i < N; i++){
    arr[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < N; j++){
      if(getRandomArbitrary(0,101) <= 10){
        arr[i][j]= false;
      } else{
        arr[i][j]= true;
      }
      
    }
  }
}

class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cell: "?",
      style: "rgba(61, 130, 139, 0.11)"
    };
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    this.props.Explosion();
  }

  handleClick() {
    const mine = <img alt="BOOM!" src={Mine}/>;
    if(this.props.children ){
     this.handleChange();
    this.setState({cell: ""})
    } else{
      this.setState({cell: mine, style:"red"})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button style={{background:  this.state.style}} className="square" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
      {this.state.cell}
    </button>
    );
  }
}

  class Field extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            arr: [],
            field: true
          };
          Fill(this.state.arr)
    }

    Explosion = () => {
      this.setState({field: false });
      console.log(1);
    };

   Rows(arr,i){
     return (
      <div className="board-row"  key={`${i}`} >
        {arr}
      </div>
     )
   }

    render() {
      for( var i = 0; i < N; i++){
          for( var j = 0; j < N; j++){
            this.state.arr[i][j] = <Square key={`${i} ${j}`}  Explosion={this.Explosion} >
              {this.state.arr[i][j]}</Square >
          }
          this.state.arr[i] = this.Rows( this.state.arr[i],i);
      }
      if (this.state.field){
        return (
          <div className="status">
            {this.state.arr}
          </div>
        );
      } else{
        return(
          <h1>You lose</h1>
        );
      }
      
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Field/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Comment: `this.state` можно присваивать только в конструкторе, в любом другом месте есть `setState`, при рендеринге вообще убийственно что-то с состоянием делать. Мне кажется, это достаточно критическое замечание, чтобы дальше не смотреть данный код. Что бы с ним дальше кто ни делал - работать все будет плохо.

Answer (score 1):

У вас [контекст теряется](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind) при передаче ф-ии потомку.
См. пример, как контекст биндить

```
this.Explosion.bind(this)
```

```js
class Field extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            arr: [],
            field: true
          };
          Fill(this.state.arr)
          
          this.Explosion = this.Explosion.bind(this) //биндим контекст, методы, кстати, принято с маленькой буквы называть
    }

    Explosion = () => {
      this.setState({field: false });
      console.log(1);
    };
    //Ваш код
  }
```

Comment: И это тоже, но основная проблема была в том что я пытался поднять состояние из элемента которого не было в return рендере родителя