# Подъём состояния React

Tags: reactjs

Здраствуйте! Подскажите возможно ли поднять состояние компонента, который не находиться в return функции рендеринга?

Comment: Как понять "не находится в return функции рендеринга"? Т.е. компонент не рендерится вообще... Тогда чего хочется добиться? Не знаю кому как, а без кода слова непонятны

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1182938/cannot-add-property-0-object-is-not-extensible-react-js-84-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0